# Simple DLL Project doesn't create any files in Output Directory after successful build

Tags: c++, dll, game-engine

I have the following code in a simple DLL project.

```
#Test.cpp

#include "Test.h"
#include <stdio.h>

namespace Samuel {

  void Print()
  {
    printf("Welcome to Samuel Engine\n");
  }

}
```

with a basic header file

```
#Test.h

#pragma once

namespace Samuel {
  __declspec(dllexport) void Print();
}
```

When I build the project there are no compilation errors, however no files are generated in the 
[Output Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDXTS.png). Is it possible I'm missing some basic step? I've tried setting 'Copy Local' to both true and false to the same results. Would appreciate any pointers

The full commandline from Linker settings is:

```
/OUT:"C:\dev\Samuel\bin\Debug-x64\Samuel\Samuel.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\dev\Samuel\bin\Debug-x64\Samuel\Samuel.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /IMPLIB:"C:\dev\Samuel\bin\Debug-x64\Samuel\Samuel.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\dev\Samuel\bin\Debug-x64\Samuel\Samuel.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"C:\dev\Samuel\bin-int\Debug-x64\Samuel\Samuel.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

And unfortunately there were no *.tlog files in the bin-int directory for me to check out.

There is this showing in the build log:

```
1>Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
1>  Task "Copy" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory)' == 'true' and '$(SkipCopyBuildProduct)' != 'true') was evaluated as ('true' == 'true' and 'true' != 'true').
```

Comment: Look at the linker settings, in particular the full command line, and look at the linker*.tlog files under the intermediate directory. Those will tell you what the linker is doing and where the files went.

Comment: I've edited my post to show the settings. Based on where the /OUT: is pointing, it should be going to the right place, but it's weird that there aren't any tlog files to check.

Comment: Are there any cl*.tlog files, or any *.log files at all? You should set msbuild output and log verbosity to diagnostic (under tools / options / projects / build and run) and see what's going on.

Comment: @dxiv there are no cl*.tlog files and only a single Samuel.log file after setting it to diagnostic. Is there anything in particular i should be checking? I've searched for "Lib" / "Output" and I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary. Is there possibly a typo or something in the Output Directory that would be causing it not to work? "$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Configuration)-$(Platform)\$(ProjectName)\"

Comment: You wrote that `there are no compilation errors` so I assume that something does compile somewhere. If you do a full rebuild of the project, you should see separate lines from the compiler and linker in the build window, and also find a number of logfiles on disk. What version of VS btw?

Comment: It's VS 2019 Version 16.5.3.

Comment: In the log there is a >Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory that is skipped.

Comment: Open the [developer command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019) matching your bitness, change directories to where the `.vcxproj` is and run `msbuild -verbosity:normal -target:rebuild <project-name>.vcxproj`. If that still doesn't answer it, try `verbosity:detailed`.

Comment: Unfortunately the build is still successful with no lib/dll/exp files produced, and the output is the same as it was previously

Comment: Don't know what the previous (full) output was, but a `-target:rebuild` should start with `_PrepareForClean`. If it does not then something is very wrong with your project file(s). You could try `verbosity:detailed` as I wrote before, but other than that I can't guess much from the distance.

Comment: It does indeed. I'm also at a loss.